Can I get rotation and location value of newly created cube by geometry node?
I use this simple geometry node setup

It just keep generating cubes when I move curve point like this.
newly created cube is rotated on z axis.

and I need to know rotation value and location value of newly created cube by geometry node. I need to use those values to move and rotate the red big cube, which I can't control via geometry node because I need to move it by armature bones, so  I would like to use rotation and location values of new cube as driver values for bones.
Is it possible to get rotation value and location value of newly created cube by this geometry node setup?

May I recommend to read this post: How to expose geometry nodes result as driver inputs ?

I checked it but I need rotation value too.
